# Cannot find a record just created in a different thread with JPA

Tags: jpa, transactions, playframework, persistence

I am using the Play! framework, and have a difficulty with in the following scenario.
I have a server process which has a 'read-only' transaction. This to prevent any possible database lock due to execution as it is a complicated procedure. There are one or two record to be stored, but I do that as a job, as I found doing them in the main thread could result in a deadlock under higher load.

However, in one occasion I need to create an object and subsequently use it. 
However, when I create the object using a Job, wait for the resulting id (with a Promise return) and then search in the database for it, it cannot be found.

Is there an easy way to have the JPA search 'afresh' in the DB at this point? I implemented a 5 sec. pause to test, so I am sue it is not because the procedure hadn't finished yet.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is a transaction wrapped around your `INSERT` and if there is one check that the transaction is `COMMIT`ed.

Comment: It is committed, and I can check it in the database (I put in a 10 second pause between creation and search). It seems to me, right or wrong, that the JPA of the parent thread does not take in account any new additions to the database.